# PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group with substring method

Tags: java

**Description**

My goal is to remove a specific part of a `String`. Here `and @ref_element='...'`.

**Error**

However I'm facing an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 97
```

The index 97 is before the last `]`.

**Code Example**

```
String s = "//frame[@id='tutu' and @name='toto' and @ref_element='Menu/Blabla/Toto/Titi/frame(id(  abcedef']"

int length = 19;
int refElementIndex = 37;
String objectPath = "Menu/Blabla/Toto/Titi/frame(id(  abcedef";
return s.replaceFirst(s.substring(refElementIndex, refElementIndex + length  + objectPath.length() + 1), "");
```

**Expected Result**

```
 //frame[@id='tutu' and @name='toto']
```

Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: `(` is a special character in regex and must be escaped

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) would have answered this.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use replaceFirst; it takes a regular expression as argument, and what you're passing in is a raw string and not in regular expression form. Just use `.replace`; this takes raw strings. (Note: this will replace every 'needle' it finds and not just the first, however, presumably that won't be a problem. If you must have replaceFirst, wrap your argument in `Pattern.quote`, so: `return s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(s.subst.....));`).